# Significance of relationship between sex and bachelor's degree or higher (2017 U.S. labor force, ages 25 and up) (disparity, difference)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sampling, chi-squared-test, population

*[Reports and webpages](https://www.google.com/search?q=educational-attainment+bachelor%27s-degree+OR+college-degree+(men+OR+male+women+OR+female)+OR+(sex+OR+gender)) like the following prompted this question:  "[Women Now at the Head of the Class, Lead Men in College Attainment](https://www.census.gov/newsroom/blogs/random-samplings/2015/10/women-now-at-the-head-of-the-class-lead-men-in-college-attainment.html)" by Kurt Bauman and Camille Ryan, October 7, 2015, United States Census Blog* Random Samplings*.  (This is not homework.)*

---

Within the context of annualized 2017 data from the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics [Current Population Survey](https://www.bls.gov/cps/home.htm), and within the U.S. civilian labor force of age 25 and over:

Was there a relationship of practical or statistical significance or both between sex and having a bachelor's degree or higher?  Why or why not?

---

The two variables -- sex and having a bachelor's degree or higher -- are both naturally dichotomous variables in the B.L.S. estimates.  As per those estimates, a person is either a man or a woman, and either has a bachelor's degree or higher or does not.

Table 1, below, contains the B.L.S. estimates<sup>1</sup> in a two-way two-by-two contingency frequency distribution table with extra rows and extra columns for displaying related numbers.  *(The last numbered note below contains this question's table data in CSV format to make it easier for you to load it into a spreadsheet or other program.)*

As can be seen, 39.69991% of the total population had a bachelor's degree or higher, but fewer than that percentage of men had a bachelor's degree or higher, and more than that percentage of women had a bachelor's degree or higher.  Accordingly, there was a disparity between the percent or rate of women who could have passed a test for having a bachelor's degree and the percent or rate of men who could have passed that test.

```
Table 1:  Numbers from and derived from 2017 B.L.S. C.P.S.

         |Civilian     |Bachelor's |          | Expected  | Difference | 
         | labor force | degree    |     %    | number at | from       |
         | age >= 25   | or higher |   (rate) | 39.69991% | expected   |
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Men      |   74,258,000| 27,781,000| 37.41146%| 29,480,360|  -1,699,360|
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Women    |   64,901,000| 27,465,000| 42.31830%| 25,765,639|  +1,699,360|
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Together |  139,159,000| 55,246,000| 39.69991%|     [n/a] |      [n/a] |
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Disparity|       [n/a] |     [n/a] | 88.40492%|     [n/a] |      [n/a] |
in rates |             |           |          |           |            |
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
```

As can be seen in Table 1, the disparity in the rates by sex was 88.40492%.  For every 100 women who had such a degree there were about 88 men who had a degree.  The total disparity as a whole number was 3,398,720.

The Table 1 estimates may be entered into [one](http://statpages.info/chisq.html) of the many online chi-square calculators to get the result **p-value<.00001**.

Again, however, those B.L.S. estimates are just that: *estimates*.  Additional insight into the apparent disparity may be gained by examining the ranges within which the B.L.S. has a degree of confidence that the actual numbers are.  The B.L.S. has provided instructions on how to determine the 95% level of confidence intervals for the estimates.<sup>2</sup>  At the 95% level of confidence, the low end and high end numbers are as follows:

```
Table 2:  B.L.S. low and high end numbers with 95% level of confidence intervals.

         |Civilian     |Civilian     |Bachelor's |Bachelor's |
         | labor force | labor force | degree    | degree    |
         | age >= 25   | age >= 25   | or higher | or higher |
         | LOW END     | HIGH END    | LOW END   | HIGH END  |
---------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
Men      |   73,635,096|   74,880,904| 27,172,805| 28,389,195|
---------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
Women    |   64,285,841|   65,516,159| 26,857,979| 28,072,021|
---------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
```

The disparity in the by-sex rates of attaining a bachelor's degree or higher can be lessened and narrowed by using those edge-case numbers as follows:  For men, use the low-end labor force number and the high-end bachelor's degree or higher number.  For women, the opposite: Use the high-end labor force number and the low-end bachelor's degree or higher number.  Those numbers may be tabulated as follows:

```
Table 3:  Table 1 but starting with edge-case least-disparate numbers based on the 95% level of confidence intervals.

         |Civilian     |Bachelor's |          | Expected  | Difference | 
         | labor force | degree    |     %    | number at | from       |
         | age >= 25   | or higher |   (rate) | 39.70296% | expected   |
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Men      |   73,635,096| 28,389,195| 38.55389%| 29,235,316|    -846,121|
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Women    |   65,516,159| 26,857,979| 40.99443%| 26,011,858|    +846,121|
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Together |  139,151,255| 55,247,174| 39.70296%|     [n/a] |      [n/a] |
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
Disparity|       [n/a] |     [n/a] | 94.04665%|     [n/a] |      [n/a] |
in rates |             |           |          |           |            |
---------|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|
```

Accordingly, the disparity -- when using the edge-case least-disparate case numbers -- in the by-sex rates of having a bachelor's degree or higher in the civilian labor force age 25 and over in 2017 was 94.04665%.  The total disparity as a whole number was 1,696,244.

Even though Table 3 is based on edge-case least-disparate numbers, the numbers still lead to the result **p-value<.00001**.

Disparities in relationships like the disparity being examined have commonly been found to be statistically significant at p-value<.05.  Additional insight into the apparent disparity may be gained by determining what the disparity would need to be to get p-value<.05 with the Table 1 estimates and then the edge-case least-disparate Table 3 numbers.

To get p-value<.05 with the Table 1 estimates, the disparity in the by-sex rates would have had to have been 99.93755% and the whole number of 17,180.  (See table 4 in the notes.)

To get p-value<.05 with the edge-case least-disparate Table 3 numbers, the disparity in the by-sex rates would have had to have been 99.93758% and the whole number of 17,190.  (See table 5 in the notes.)

In other words, the disparity is perhaps 1,696,244 to 3,398,720 human individuals greater than the approximately 17,190 individuals it would need to be less than to attribute the disparity to chance.

---

***NOTES:***

1. The B.L.S. numbers are based on the B.L.S. 2017 "Current Population Survey" ("CPS") numbers in thousands [here](https://www.bls.gov/cps/cpsaat03.htm) and [here](https://www.bls.gov/cps/cpsaat07.htm).  For example, Table 1's "Civilian labor force age >= 25" numbers are based on the following simple addition:

   - Men = ages 25 to 54 years (54,813,000) + ages 55 to 64 years (14,156,000) + ages 65 years and over (5,289,000) = 74,258,000
   - Women = ages 25 to 54 years (47,870,000) + ages 55 to 64 years (12,743,000) + ages 65 years and over (4,288,000) = 64,901,000

   The data is also available with unweighted record counts from the U.S. Census Bureau's [CPS Table Creator](https://www.census.gov/cps/data/cpstablecreator.html).
2. From K. Kosanovich, B.L.S. Economist, 2018-03-06~16:59EST:  * * *  Information about the reliability of estimates from the CPS and how to construct approximate standard errors and confidence intervals is online at https://www.bls.gov/cps/documentation.htm#reliability. * * * There are several ways to construct a confidence interval.  For example, you can calculate one for the estimate of the number men in the civilian labor force ages 25 and over in 2017 (an annual average).  I’ll briefly review one example using the guidance in the PDF file about calculating standard errors online at https://www.bls.gov/cps/documentation.htm#reliability and the parameters and factors provided in the XLSX file at that link. * * * In 2017, for example, there were 27,781,000 men in the labor force with a bachelor’s degree and higher.  I’ll choose [parameters and factors in table PF-4](https://www.bls.gov/cps/parameters-and-factors-for-calculating-standard-errors.xlsx) for an annual average number of people with a bachelor’s degree where a = -0.0001858, b = 12882.76, and f = 0.67.  To [calculate the standard error](https://www.bls.gov/cps/calculating-standard-errors-and-confidence-intervals.pdf) for an annual average level, the formula is  se(x) = f * squareroot[ax2 + bx].  In this case, the standard error of 27,781,000 = 0.67 * squareroot [ (-0.0001858 * 27,781,000 * 27,781,000) + (12882.76 * 27,781,000) ] or 310,304.  To create a 90-percent confidence interval, we multiply the standard error by 1.645, resulting in 510,450 or approximately plus or minus 510.  We have a 90-percent confidence that the number of men in the labor force with a bachelor’s degree or more was 27,781,000 plus or minus approximately 510,000. You can construct confidence intervals for women with a bachelor’s degree or more using the same parameters and factors.  For men or women in the labor force age 25 and over, you can use the parameters and factors for men and women 20 years and over from table PF-1.
3. A previous version of this question that commenters referenced featured the story "[Why Men Are the New College Minority](https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2017/08/why-men-are-the-new-college-minority/536103/)" by Jon Marcus, August 8, 2017, *The Atlantic*.
4. The tables in CSV format are as follows:

   ```
   Table 1:  Numbers from and derived from 2017 B.L.S. C.P.S.,,,,,
   ,Civilian labor force age >= 25,Bachelor's degree or higher,% (rate),Expected number at 39.69991%,Difference from expected
   Men,74258000,27781000,37.41146%,29480360,-1699360
   Women,64901000,27465000,42.31830%,25765640,1699360
   Together,139159000,55246000,39.69991%,[n/a],[n/a]
   Disparity in rates,[n/a],[n/a],88.40492%,[n/a],[n/a]
   ,,,,,
   Table 2:  B.L.S. low and high end numbers based on the 95% level of confidence intervals.,,,,,
   ,Civilian labor force age >= 25 LOW END,Civilian labor force age >= 25 HIGH END,Bachelor's degree or higher LOW END,Bachelor's degree or higher HIGH END,
   Men,73635096,74880904,27172805,28389195,
   Women,64285841,65516159,26857979,28072021,
   ,,,,,
   Table 3:  Table 1 but with edge-case least-disparate numbers based on the 95% level of confidence intervals.,,,,,
   ,Civilian labor force age >= 25,Bachelor's degree or higher,% (rate),Expected number at 39.70296%,Difference from expected
   Men,73635096,28389195,38.55389%,29235316,-846121
   Women,65516159,26857979,40.99443%,26011858,846121
   Together,139151255,55247174,39.70296%,[n/a],[n/a]
   Disparity in rates,[n/a],[n/a],94.04665%,[n/a],[n/a]
   ,,,,,
   Table 4:  Table 1 labor force numbers with degree numbers equidistant from the expected number to get p-value<.05,,,,,
   ,Civilian labor force age >= 25,Bachelor's degree or higher,% (rate),Expected number at 39.69991%,Difference from expected
   Men,74258000,29471770,39.68834%,29480360,-8590
   Women,64901000,25774229,39.71315%,25765639,8590
   Together,139159000,55245999,39.69991%,[n/a],[n/a]
   Disparity in rates,[n/a],[n/a],99.93755%,[n/a],[n/a]
   ,,,,,
   Table 5:  Table 3 edge-case least-disparate labor force numbers with degree numbers equidistant from the expected number to get p-value<.05,,,,,
   ,Civilian labor force age >= 25,Bachelor's degree or higher,% (rate),Expected number at 39.70296%,Difference from expected
   Men,73635096,29226721,39.69129%,29235316,-8595
   Women,65516159,26020453,39.71608%,26011858,8595
   Together,139151255,55247174,39.70296%,[n/a],[n/a]
   Disparity in rates,[n/a],[n/a],99.93758%,[n/a],[n/a]
   ```

Comment: Please elaborate on the meaning you attach to "strong" in your question.  If this is intended as a synonym for "statistically significant," then what do you view as a population or process and what do you view as a sample?  Also, are you aware that these statistics are *estimates* and not actual data?  That makes it impossible to apply any statistical test to the numbers you have displayed: you need to know the data from which they were derived.

Comment: There is no statistically significant relationship to be found because these are population level data. The interpretation and meaning of a $p$-value is not applicable to this setting. Census estimates come from complex statistical surveys with weights and stratified sampling, so most of their predictions should be accompanied by uncertainty intervals. However, you do not seem to have that information.

Comment: I like it how the article says that university is doing more athletics to attract more men since they became a minority. it's like hitting people in the head with a hammer to increase funding for brain research

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your comment, and I've tried to revise the text  to address your concerns.  I originally used "statistically significant", but a suggested edit changed it to "strong".  I've changed it back.  Yes, I'm aware these are estimates.  Could their levels of uncertainty reasonably and not just hypothetically be so significant that they preclude a determination of the statistical significance I am seeking?

Comment: That's a great question, Jon.  The first place I would look for answers would be the BLS itself: they publish their methodology, if not their raw data, and I would expect them to be clear about margins of error in their estimates.  Even Census data themselves have margins of error if only because whatever data are used are no longer current: they are based on samples for years that are not multiples of 10. BTW, you will find that age is an important mediator: there will be proportionally more males with degrees among older people and fewer among younger people.

Comment: @Adam0 thank you for your comment.  I revised my question and added info about the B.L.S. methodology and level of confidence.

Comment: @AdamO - In relation to your comment that "There is no statistically significant relationship to be found because these are population level data.  The interpretation and meaning of a p-value is not applicable to this setting."  Thank you for that comment.  However, we do not actually have population level data.  We only have estimates of the actual population level data, and --per the B.L.S.-- "There is about a 90-percent chance, or level of confidence, that an estimate based on a sample will differ by no more than 1.6 standard errors from the true population value because of sampling error."

Comment: @JonFreed yes but those values are *derived* from survey estimates and cannot be analyzed. There are separate methods, much more complex, that you must use to analyze data of this form. Most importantly, you need the actual raw survey data and the weighting they've applied to it.

Comment: @AdamO, thank you --   Are those separate methods in a category with a name, or what are the names of some of those methods, please?  I'd like to learn more about them.  I tried searching for 
"determining statistical significance of relationship in estimates derived from samples", but I did not get any results that were clearly pointing me towards the methods you've referenced (or, more likely, I just didn't recognize them).  Thank you

Comment: I also tried searching for "using estimates to then determine statistical significance of relationship" and variations of both searches.

Comment: @JonFreed yes "survey statistics" will generally yield some results, it's a bit unfortunate there isn't more discussion on the topic on this site, but I suspect statisticians working in this area are more silo'ed. The R package `survey` has an accompanying text, and numerous vignettes (see, for instance `vignette('survey', package='survey')` after calling `library(survey)`) if you're interested in some professional development in this area.

Comment: @AdamO - Thank you.  Might not make any difference, but I received confidence level info from the B.L.S. and I added it to the question.  I am reviewing the survey package [homepage](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/) and I went through its link 'Tests of association' to its page 'Tests in contingency tables' with its text about chi squared from an estimate being too large, samples being much smaller, rescaling, and using the F distribution, the "second-order Rao-Scott adjustment" for the rescaled statistic.  It seems the appropriate next step in that direction is to "rescale".

Comment: And I discovered that the U.S. Census Bureau's version of this data includes "unweighted record counts".  https://www.census.gov/cps/data/cpstablecreator.html

Comment: @JonFreed very good. If you just get the stratum weights and the sampling probabilities, you can start doing census-level survey statistics.

Comment: @peter-flom Please see my SE network and LinkedIn profiles and you'll see I'm nowhere near any homework. :) The referenced help center page has no info about "self study" questions.  I've looked at the https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask page, and my question seems to fit the suggestion that "if your motivation is 'I would like others to explain ______ to me', then you are probably OK".  My question seems to fit the guidance regarding a constructive subjective question that could "inspire answers that explain 'why' and 'how'".  Please advise.

Comment: *Was there a relationship of practical or statistical significance or both between sex and having a bachelor's degree or higher? Why or why not?* Why are you comparing with the **labour force** instead of the total population (also non-working)? There is a clear difference in the number of men and women among the labour force. This makes that any approach will show a strong and clear significant difference. What is your goal with answering this question? At least it is not a particularly good case to explain the theory and different approaches because it is not in a gray area.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings , thank you for the comment! Why? I want to know if the disparity between the percent of women who could have passed a pre-employment or job application screening test for having a bachelor's degree versus the percent of men is significant. My goal is to determine if the disparity is statistically or practically significant or both or neither. Such a test can have real-life consequences.  (Also, thank you for drafting an answer (since deleted). I'm curious about why a chi-square test should not be used, if indeed that is the case, and what  should be used instead.)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and answers so far.  So far, @ AdamO's comment that prompted me to do confidence levels and  @ Sal's answer that prompted me to think about "effect size" have been the most valuable to me.  I am still hoping that before the bounty period ends an answerer will make an argument for the disparity not existing (due to some error in my figures or the B.L.S. numbers or something else) or for the disparity being insignificant.

Comment: *"...who could have passed a pre-employment or job application screening test for having a bachelor's degree..."* Could you spell this out more clearly?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings - Employers require applicants for many jobs to have a bachelor's degree or higher.  They "test" or "screen" applicants for whether they have a bachelor degree, and reject those that do not.  Such tests can often be simple questions an applicant must answer as part of their application, like "Do you have a bachelor's degree or higher?"  Such screens can involve reviewing applicants' answers to such questions or their resumes, and then the rejection of applicants who do not have what the employer wants.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I get that now. But  now a new question boils up. How do you wish to connect this screening to demographic data. Why are you using the demographic data to express something about this screening?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings , Until now, I tried not to describe why a significant rel. between sex and a bach. deg. or higher could matter because I want analysis to not be influenced by it. The U.S. generally prohibits employers from using screens that have a significantly disparate impact on applicants of one sex (or race, etc). Some employers require a degree, but not in any specific field, while also not permitting any level of experience in lieu of that non-specific degree, not even decades of experience in analytical or management roles. Trends indicate such tests will affect more and more males.

Comment: I would like to express whether such tests do or do not have a significantly disparate impact on males.  An appropriate subsequent question is whether a non-specific bachelor's degree is a bona fide occupational qualification when no level of experience is allowed in lieu of such a non-specific degree.  However, that is indeed a separate and subsequent question.  The question of statistical and practical significance comes first.

Comment: The reason that I am asking is because there are so many different ways to view relationship between sex and bachelor's degree, when the relationship is not specified. - For instance one could also view the group of people with a bachelor's degree and view how many of the men have jobs and how many of the women have jobs. In that case there is *no* significant difference. - Your goals are still very unclear to me (making it difficult to get the context of significance). I have little idea how you *apply* the difference men/women, what you do (need) with it in your further research on screening

Comment: @Martijn Weterings I am looking at equal opportunity in hiring.  Analyses about equal opportunity in hiring start with the applicant pool. I'm looking at jobs that have a U.S. pool with both those that do and do not have a job, and people under 25 are unlikely to have enough experience to make up for the lack of a degree. The next step is to divide the pool by those who can and cannot pass the test and the protected class's groups: males and females. The result is a 2x2 table. If the percentage of each sex that can pass the test differs then there is a disparate impact, but is it significant?

Comment: How do you define equal opportunity (and if you do this in terms of disparity and quantitative numbers then what are the limits)? Are you looking for statistical significance or some other measure of difference?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings To be significant, the disparity must be both statistically significant (generally at p-value<.05) and of practical significance. "Practical" is not well defined. It has been related to the quantity impacted; the whole number of people impacted (versus the percentage).  It has also been related to the quality of the impact. For example, the impact of a hiring decision on a person who already has a job is arguably less than a person who does not have a job.  It has also been related to how much the employer could afford to spend on revising the test to eliminate the impact.

Comment: Thank you all again for the insightful comments and answers in the bounty period.  All three answers address statistical significance.  Sal Mangiafico and Martijn Weterings address practical significance, Sal more so through the analysis of effect size.  I will wait to award the bounty until the window is almost expired, at which time I will consider any additional votes and comments that have been made.

Answer (score 2):

I'll weigh in with one point, but make it an answer so I can include some code and results.

I think the way I would approach the question is to consider the effect size.

If I have understood the question and data correctly, *phi* for the appropriate table comes out to 0.05.  Cohen (1988) interprets this value as less than "small".  Obviously, any interpretation of effect size is relative to the discipline and intention of the analysis.  But the size of the effect does suggest that it may not large enough to get us too excited.

The following is code in R.

```
if(!require(psych)){install.packages("psych")}

Men.no.bachelors = 74258000 - 27781000
Men.no.bachelors

Women.no.bachelors = 64901000 - 27465000
Women.no.bachelors

Input =("
Sex       No.bachelors      Bachelors
  Men     46477000          27781000
  Women   37436000          27465000
")

Matrix = as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(Input),
                   header=TRUE,
                   row.names=1))

prop.table(Matrix, margin=1)

   ### c     No.bachelors Bachelors
   ### Men      0.6258854 0.3741146
   ### Women    0.5768170 0.4231830

library(psych)

phi(Matrix,
    digits = 4)

   ### [1] 0.05
```

---

References

Cohen, J. 1988. Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences, 2nd Edition. Routledge.

Comment: "Effect size" leads to Abelson's paradox and the aspirin anecdote by Rosnow & Rosenthal (2003; "effect size index rφ [phi] [only] .034" but "unethical to continue to give ... a placebo"). RE the above question, the "total disparity as a whole number was 3,398,720", so whoever made a non-specific bachelor's degree a barrier to entry did, in effect, summarily exclude about that many individuals of one sex versus the other from any further consideration despite the reasonable idea that the excluded individuals were otherwise statistically indistinguishable from the included individuals. Thoughts?

Comment: It's a good point. We shouldn't conflate Cohen's "size" interpretations with meaningfulness.   In matters of life and death, a tiny effect size can matter to those involved (aspirin example).   And small effects repeated many times can be meaningful (Abelson example).  And some fields have different expectations.  There was recently an election in Pennsylvania that switched from 60/40 for one party two years prior to 50/50 with the other party winning.  That's a small effect size, but was considered a newsworthy shift in this context.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few confusions at the base of this question that need to be addressed at the outset.  As stated, your question asks about sex differences in the attainment of tertiary degrees; this question makes no mention of workforce participation, and hence, data on that metric is not relevant to your question as it is presently stated.  However, your use of the data suggests that you are actually interested in sex differences in the attainment of tertiary degrees *only among adults participating in the workforce*.  For the remainder of this post I am going to assume that your question is misstated, and your actual interest is in the latter issue.  If you are interested in sex differences across the whole of the corresponding adult population (i.e., all U.S. civilians age 25 and over, including those not in the workforce) then you should be comparing numbers of tertiary degrees to the number of men and women in the population, and you would need to get estimates of those values.

Having made an assumption about your interest here, the next step is to recognise that you are using outputs from census surveys.  These outputs are not data - they are population *estimates* calculated from raw data held by the census bureau.  The estimates should be accompanied by estimates of standard error, so you will need to obtain that information from the census material to get an idea of the accuracy of these estimates.  Using the 95% CIs you have given, it is simple to reverse-engineer the standard errors of the estimates, which gives the following information:

> ```
>                 Civilian Labour Force         With Tertiary Degrees           
>                 Estimate  |  Std Err          Estimate  |  Std Err   
> Men           74,258,000  |  317814.0       27,781,000  |  310309.3
> Women         64,901,000  |  313862.4       27,465,000  |  309710.3
> ```

As other commentators have pointed out in the comments to your post, these estimates come from complex survey techniques that generally use stratified sampling methods combined with complex inferential methods.  Ideally you would approach this matter by obtaining the raw census data and using this to get a direct estimate of the proportion of tertiary degree holders of each sex, with appropriate standard errors.  I am going to assume that this raw data is not available, or even if it is, that this kind of analysis is too onerous.

The next best thing would be to use the above estimates as your "data" and perform your test using this information.  This involves the analysis of a $2 \times 2$ [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) with misclassification, with estimated standard errors for this misclassification being given in your census information.  There is a substantial amount of [literature on the analysis of contingency tables with misclassification](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22contingency+tables%22+%22misclassification%22&btnG=), and this is a fairly complex area, owing to the variations on the problem and the difficulties of analysis.  In your particular case you have estimated totals for the tertiary-degree holders of each sex and the row totals of all men and women in the labour force, and both are subject to misclassification error with estimated standard errors given.

**My suggestion:** If you would like to conduct a formal test for sex differences in the proportion of tertiary degree-holders, I would suggest that your next job is to review the literature on the analysis of contingency tables with misclassification.  Having a look at the numbers, I think it is obvious that you are going to see statistically significant evidence of a difference, but this is because you are comparing the sexes *based only on people in the workforce*.  If you were to use population estimates that include people not in the workforce then I would imagine that this difference vanishes.

Comment: Thank you for the response and suggestion! Clarification: The bold text does indeed have "no mention of workforce participation", but it is prefaced by this text: "Within the context of annualized 2017 data from the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics Current Population Survey, and within the U.S. civilian labor force of age 25 and over:"  Is it fair to summarize your response as: "Having a look at the numbers, I think it is obvious that you are going to see statistically significant evidence of a [relationship between sex and having a bachelor's degree or higher among] people in the workforce"?

Comment: Yes, that is fair - if you restrict attention to that group then you see that there are far more men in the population, but the raw numbers of degrees are roughly equal, so the proportion of degree-holders (bachelor or higher) for women will be larger.

Comment: Thank you for that response!  Regarding "misclassification", isn't that already accounted for within my question's "Table 2" that is based on the Bureau's standard error and confidence intervals?  And ultimately, is it realistic that any "misclassification" is large enough that it means that we cannot say whether the apparent disparity is statistically significant or of practical significance?  Based on the numbers in Table 2 and the least-disparate case numbers in Table 3, such a large "misclassification" seems unrealistic.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  The method you have used is a conservative method that looks at the bounds of their interval.  I am suggesting that if you want your own direct estimate of the quantity of interest, with confidence bounds, you will need to use some kind of contingency table method with misclassification.

Answer (score 1):

**I will focus on the aspect of statistical significance and your calculations** and tell why they are wrong.

*To give a more refined question that talks about 'practical' significance is a bit more difficult. Not only is this topic a bit more subjective (though you can already find several posts on this website about different interpretations of the term 'significance' that at least explains the aspects involved), it is also difficult because your goals are not so clear. Your title has a general question 'relationship between sex and bachelor's degree' but it becomes confusing due to the different ways that one can look at it (absolute numbers, relative, different intersections of ages, etcetera). It is questionable whether the (single) statistic that you use is good for your purpose, and it makes interpretation of 'practical significance' even more subjective/difficult.*

**You should not use the chi-square test the way you do (on derived numbers and not original counts)** (I am not sure whether you did this also in your second calculation which is a bit fuzzy, but it is true at least for your first calculation).

The (Pearsons) chi-square test uses an estimate of binomial distributed data by approximating with a normal distribution that has the same variance/deviation. But your data is not binomial distributed. The numbers are not direct counts (the chi-square test needs to be applied to count data). Instead the values are obtained from a survey among 60 000 households. This will make your estimate of the relative standard error much smaller than reality.

Example (an extreme example to make the point more clear). If you would  survey *only* hundred women and find out that $36$ have a bsc or higher. Then this has an standard deviation of $\sqrt{36}=6$ or $17\%$. However if you recalculate it to the entire female population, say some $36 000 000$ have a bsc or higher, then you'd naively compute a standard deviation of $\sqrt{36 000 000} = 6000$ or $0.017\%$ .

Based on the 60 000 households (america has roughly 126 million). You could say that the factor by which the survey-counts are inflated is 2100 (in reality it is a bit more complicated when corrections are added for the composition of households and a weighted sum is made instead of a simple multiplication by 2100). Then the observed counts are more something like (I use https://www.bls.gov/cps/cpsaat07.htm):

```
 - total women > 25 yrs:           112 872 000  -> 53 749                
 - total men > 25 yrs:             104 057 000  -> 49 551            
 - total working women > 25 yrs:    64 901 000  -> 30 905            
 - total working men > 25 yrs:      74 258 000  -> 35 361            
 - working women >25 >=bsc:         27 465 000  -> 13 079               
 - working men >25 >=bsc:           27 781 000  -> 13 229
```

The relative s.e. for the estimated fractions will be roughly $\sqrt{\frac{1-\hat{p}}{n\hat{p}}}$ or close to 0.5%.

When you take a confidence interval roughly $\pm2SE$ then you have half the 4% which you see in your table (not bad for such simple approach, then there is more than just sampling errors, and also this calculation is just an estimate using the simple factor 2100 which in reality is more complicated).

**You should not combine the two variables like you do in your second correlation** You take the worst case of the maximum and the minimum. But the observations in the sample are likely correlated. If you observe more/less people with a bsc (or higher) and a job then, conditioned on this, you would expect more/less people with a job. You could assume the observation as a contingency table (now you *can* use a chisquared test since they are original counts, or at least something that resembles it)  with the margins fixed (this is not a correct assumption, but much more practical and does not generate too much of an error, if you'd like you could compute more complicated solutions, ie. exact tests):

```
           men       women      total
>=bsc      13229     13079      26308
<bsc       22132     17826      39994
total      35361     30905      66302
```

Then $\chi^2(1) = 165.79$ and $p < 10^{-16}$

So it is still a big significant result. (Why do you think it should be different? Or at least you seem to desire a result that shows it is *not* significant)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I am reviewing it.  Very glad to have it.

Comment: I have some work to do before I can claim to understand all of what you have written, but allow me to jump to the concluding statement and question:  "So, it is still a big significant result. Why do you think it should be different?"  I do not think it should be different.  I am quite confident that there is a statistically significant disparity.  However, I want to ensure my confidence is justified.  One way to do that is to ask people to try to convince me that I am wrong.  Thank you again for the answer!