# How to find relationship between two nominal categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data

I have a problem which requires to find relationship between two nominal categorical variables. What can be used to find such relatioship?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V this may be of interest, and you could search this site for questions that mention it

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339577/interpreting-cramers-v-results might be helpful

Comment: Hi! You should mention what these two variables are and what your data look like, because there may be other options than what is suggested in the current answer and comments. But it depends on the details on your situation. For instance, is at least one of your variables binary? Is the relationship you're interested in directional? (e.g. do you want to know to what extent geographical origin predicts success) Are the data paired? Is your data your whole population of interest, or just a sample? etc.

Comment: Categorical variables are for example "Body style" of cars, and "Drive train" type of cars.

Comment: How was the data sampled? How many observations do you have? And what is the problem you're trying to solve ultimately? (You mention you have a problem, but you don't state what it is exactly). You should edit your question to mention all that, rather than answering in the comment section (otherwise no one will see the additional information you're providing; for my part, I just saw your last comment out of luck). The simplest thing to do would be to share the contingency table of your data. I know it looks like a lot of questions, but it is helpful to give you a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most classical ways would probably be using the Chi-Square test to prove (or reject) the independence of two categorical variables. In this test, the null hypothesis is that the variables are independent, so if the resulting p-value is lower than 0.05 (5%) you can reject it and conclude that there's a relationship between them.

There are plenty of ways to visualize two categorical variables, but a simple one that I find particularly useful in R is just plotting a table, see a dummy example below:

```
dat1 <- factor(rep(c('a','b','c'), each = 5))
dat2 <- factor(c('no','yes','yes','no','no','yes','no','yes','yes','no','yes','no','yes','yes','yes'))
plot(table(dat1,dat2), col = c('green','blue'))
```

[image: Dummy plot]

This type of representation show for each column the distribution of the observations among the categories in the rows.